Higher number of "major-faults" when running a unittest inside of a docker container
We have a test, which we run with the perf tool to analyze the differing performance of a baremetal environment and a dockerized one.
In our baremetal environment, the same test runs slightly faster and has much fewer "major-faults":
% perf stat -e cache-references,cache-misses,major-faults,minor-faults pytest test_example.py -vv     

================================================================================== test session starts ==================================================================================
platform linux -- Python 3.8.10, pytest-6.2.5, py-1.11.0, pluggy-1.0.0 -- /usr/bin/python3
cachedir: .pytest_cache
plugins: cov-3.0.0
collected 1 item                                                                                                                                                                        

test_example.py PASSED                                                           [100%]

================================================================================== 1 passed in 11.36s ===================================================================================

 Performance counter stats for 'pytest test_example.py -vv':

         269450363      cache-references                                            
          17442918      cache-misses              #    6.474 % of all cache refs    
                36      major-faults                                                
            115959      minor-faults                                                

      12.435529552 seconds time elapsed

      10.763881000 seconds user
       1.220403000 seconds sys

When we dockerize the test on a machine with identical hardware specs, we output
%perf stat -e cache-references,cache-misses,major-faults,minor-faults pytest test_example.py -vv
============================================================================ test session starts ============================================================================
platform linux -- Python 3.10.12, pytest-8.3.3, pluggy-1.5.0 -- /usr/bin/python3
cachedir: .pytest_cache
plugins: cov-5.0.0
collected 1 item                                                                                                                                                            

test_example.py        PASSED                                               [100%]

============================================================================ 1 passed in 12.59s =============================================================================

 Performance counter stats for 'pytest test_example.py -vv':

         280330704      cache-references                                            
          17349907      cache-misses              #    6.189 % of all cache refs    
              8321      major-faults                                                
             93524      minor-faults                                                

      13.209089176 seconds time elapsed

      12.333174000 seconds user
       0.797724000 seconds sys

This indicates that the 8000+ major faults compared to the 36 on baremetal might be the reason for the performance decrease. I tried modifying some settings when launching the interactive docker container, such as
docker run --privileged -it \
  --cpus="6.0" \
  --memory="20g" \
  --shm-size="20g" \                    
  --network="host" \
  -v /cache:/cache my_image /bin/bash

which is more than enough memory for this test, but the number of major-faults remains at around 8000 alongside the lower performance. What else can we do to try to avoid runtime harddrive accesses inside our container?

Can you [edit] the question to include a [mcve]?  Your docker run command seems to be running an interactive shell instead of the standard container process, and disables standard Docker networking; does this make a difference?  You're observing low-level statistics of the kernel managing the CPU page table, does this make any observable difference in your application performance?  Are you using a language that's close enough to the hardware that your code can have any influence over this?
